# Extract function error in oracle invalid extract source

Tags: sql, oracle

I was trying to extract minute from a datetime field . But i am getting  the below issue . Please share any thoughts.

```
code :-
select extract( minute from UPD_Action_STRT_Holi_update ) from my table

Error
ORA-30076: invalid extract field for extract source

Sample Data :-
UPD_Action_STRT_Holi_update 
9/3/2021 12:39:27 PM
``
Extract source is datetime field
```

Comment: please show the table DDL

Comment: What is "datetime"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Oracle does not have a `DATETIME` data type; it has either a `DATE` or a `TIMESTAMP` and they both have year, month, day, hour, minute and second components; `TIMESTAMP` can, optionally, have fractional seconds and time zone components.

You get that error if your column has the `DATE` data type.

The [`EXTRACT` function documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions050.htm) states that:

> you can extract only `YEAR`, `MONTH`, and `DAY` from a `DATE` value.

If you want to use `EXTRACT` to get the `MINUTE` value then cast the `DATE` to a `TIMESTAMP`:

```sql
select extract( minute from CAST(UPD_Action_STRT_Holi_update AS TIMESTAMP) )
from   my_table
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=af318e949baff75797164697643e958d)*